# How do you spell short vowel sounds?

Tags: vowels

Newbie here.

If I wanted to spell out the sounds short vowels make, would these be accurate? 
a - ah,
e - eh,
i - ee,
o - ou,
u - uh

Comment: In what system? For example, that would not be correct in [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Vowels), not even close.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to teach kids the short vowel sounds. a - ah - ah-choo! e - eh - ehhh? i - ee - eeek! o - ou - ouch! u - uh - uh-oh

Comment: The alternative to IPA would be to use words that have the relevant vowels (in your accent). And ideally find minimal pairs such as "hit"/"heat"

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to use standard but specialized symbols.

- ɑ as in *father*.
- æ as in *ham*.
- ɛ as in *dress*.
- ɪ as in *kit*.
- ɔ as in *fought*.
- ʌ as in *cut*.

There’s also:

- ə as in the unstressed syllable of  *about*.
- ɝ as in *nurse*.
- ɚ as in the unstressed syllable of *farmer*.

and several more like those.

This is because no so-called “spelling pronunciations” are unambiguous in all cases and accent-neutral.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to teach kids the short vowel sounds. a - ah - ah-choo!  e - eh - ehhh?  i - ee - eeek!  o - ou - ouch!  u - uh - uh-oh

Comment: @Hetty - This is near impossible.  For example, the vowel *a* can have a wide range of sounds; such as the *a* in *hat* and the *a* in *father*.  This is why we use IPA.

Comment: I assume you mean **not** accent neutral.

Comment: @JamesRandom No, no spelling pronunciations are accent neutral. They are all of them not accent neutral.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry, I missed the "no" earlier in the sentence.

Comment: As an example, I remember looking at a Japanese phrase book in a bookshop but decided it wasn't for me when it had '*a as in pot*' (in my accent either '*a as in pat*' or '*o as in pot*' would work)